# Why does SE not answer people with not enough knowledge on a topic?

Tags: discussion

In my SE experience, I have noticed many questions which were asked by unexperienced users. The quick reply was either a quick answer with not much effort in explaining. This has happened many times in MSE. So the question is, why do SE users always expect that others are at the same level as them?

Comment: Relevant: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).

Comment: No it is not toxic to downvote. Your question is ill formed, provides no examples or evidence for your claim, accuses to very people you are asking for help of discriminating against a certain group and then you call everyone toxic. This is not your safe space, you are required to ask well written, high quality questions and back up you accusations with facts. I am sorry too be hard on you but this mentality of "You should help me, my way and like it or you are all toxic" really gets my goat.

Comment: How much effort did those unexperienced user put in? Could you tell from the question? And I don't mean sentences like *I searched for hours*.

Answer (score 13):

> Why do SE users always expect that others are at the same level as them?

This is just a wild and wrong assumption. I don't expect others to be in same level as me.

When I answer, I usually try to give short  and focused answer.

Sometimes I put little effort into it, sometimes lots of efforts.

I do try to explain "from scratch" if needed, or if asked to in comments.

And that's about it. Can't think of anything else to add.